# Hibernate 4.3.5 - What is the use of the hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, configuration, entitymanager

In the distribution package of Hibernate version 4.3.5, inside **/lib/jpa/** folder we have a **hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar** file.

I wanted to know when is this jar used.

Hibernate documentation says that **hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar** defines Hibernate support for JPA.

Does it mean that if I want to use Hibernate as JPA provider then I should be using this jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you plan on using JPA's entity manager and entity manager factory than you should definitely have this jar in your class-path.

You might also include hibernate-jpa-2.0-api or hibernate-jpa-2.1-api to have the JPA reference classes too (interfaces, annotations).

If you use the specific Hibernate API than you only need these modules:

- hibernate-core
- hibernate-commons-annotations
- hibernate-annotations